# How to convert a column from string to array in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe converted from an inherited dataset which looks like the following:

```
data = [("[]","2000","M",False),
            ("[{'username':'aabb','points':'200','active':'true'}, {'username':'bbaa22','points':'0','active':'false'}]","1999","F",True),
            ("[{'username':'topuser','points':'855','active':'false'}]","1974","M",True),
            ("[]","2005","F",False),
            ("[{'username':'myprimary','points':'1050','active':'true'}, {'username':'mylurk','points':'100','active':'true'}, {'username':'closedlurk','points':'50','active':'false'}]","1992","M",True)
            ]

columns=["user","dob_year","gender","member"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
```

```
+--------------------+--------+------+------+
|                user|dob_year|gender|member|
+--------------------+--------+------+------+
|                  []|    2000|     M| false|
|[{'username':'aab...|    1999|     F|  true|
|[{'username':'top...|    1974|     M|  true|
|                  []|    2005|     F| false|
|[{'username':'myp...|    1992|     M|  true|
+--------------------+--------+------+------+
```

I need to extract some of the elements from the `user` column and I attempt to use the pyspark `explode` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df2 = df.select(explode(df.user), df.dob_year)
```

When I attempt this, I'm met with the following error:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`user`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;

When I run `df.printSchema()`, I realize that the user column is string, rather than list as desired.

I also attempted to cast the strings in the column to arrays by creating a UDF

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = df.withColumn("user", str2list_udf(f.col("user"))).withColumn("user",df.user.cast(ArrayType(StringType())))
```

When I do that, I'm met with the following error:

> AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`user`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to array;

How can the data in this column be cast or converted into an array so that the explode function can be leveraged and individual keys parsed out into their own columns (example: having individual columns for `username`, `points` and `active`)? If explode isn't the best method, is there another route I should follow?

If it's helpful, here is the UDF that I created:

```
def str2list(x):
  if x == '[]':
    return list()
  else:
    return list(x)

str2list_udf = udf(lambda x: str2list(x))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the stringified arrays into array of structs using `from_json` the explode the resulting array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, ArrayType, StringType, StructType

user_schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField("username", StringType(), True),
        StructField("points", StringType(), True),
        StructField("active", StringType(), True)
    ])
)

df1 = (df.withColumn("user", F.from_json("user", user_schema))
       .selectExpr("inline(user)", "dob_year", "gender", "member")
       )

df1.show()
#+----------+------+------+--------+------+------+
#|  username|points|active|dob_year|gender|member|
#+----------+------+------+--------+------+------+
#|      aabb|   200|  true|    1999|     F|  true|
#|    bbaa22|     0| false|    1999|     F|  true|
#|   topuser|   855| false|    1974|     M|  true|
#| myprimary|  1050|  true|    1992|     M|  true|
#|    mylurk|   100|  true|    1992|     M|  true|
#|closedlurk|    50| false|    1992|     M|  true|
#+----------+------+------+--------+------+------+
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you very much.

Comment: This answer is ridiculously difficult to find, thank you